# Pymavlink Type Mask ValueError

Tags: python

```
from pymavlink import mavutil

# Start a connection listening to a UDP port
the_connection = mavutil.mavlink_connection('udpin:localhost:14551')

# Wait for the first heartbeat
#   This sets the system and component ID of remote system for the link
the_connection.wait_heartbeat()
print("Heartbeat from system (system %u component %u)" %
      (the_connection.target_system, the_connection.target_component))


the_connection.mav.send(mavutil.mavlink.MAVLink_set_position_target_local_ned_message(10, the_connection.target_system,
                         the_connection.target_component, mavutil.mavlink.MAV_FRAME_LOCAL_NED, int(0b110111111000), 70, 0, -10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

I have a function like below to move the drone. And the function works.(The drone goes to a designated area.)

```
the_connection.mav.send(mavutil.mavlink.MAVLink_set_position_target_local_ned_message(10, the_connection.target_system,
                         the_connection.target_component, mavutil.mavlink.MAV_FRAME_LOCAL_NED, int(0b110111111000), 70, 0, -10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

there is a variable named type_mask in this function and the value of the variable in the function is **int(0b11011111111000)**

I want the user to enter the values from a bash interface and control the drone. I changed my function like this.

```
the_connection.mav.send(mavutil.mavlink.MAVLink_set_position_target_local_ned_message(10, the_connection.target_system,
                          the_connection.target_component, mavutil.mavlink.MAV_FRAME_LOCAL_NED, int(type_mask), float(x), float(y), float(z), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, int(yaw),int(yaw_rate)))
```

But when I get the type_mask value from the user in the interface using **input()**, I get a **ValueError**. I am aware of this because there is **"b"** in the **type_mask**.

How can I run the function by getting the type_mask value from the user with input().

Thank you kind regards..